# Saving instance state on hybrid apps

Tags: javascript, cordova, hybrid-mobile-app

I just wonder if there is any way to persist data on hybrid app when the app crashes/ended/paused. i have tried using onpause, saving data and retreived data on onresume, but it didnt work. The reason being the app is destroyed and recreated.Can anyone say how to save instance states in hybrid apps

Answer (score 0):

You can use local storage , this will do what you are looking for. but i would not recommend this as it is not that secure.

To save: 
localStorage.setItem("name","value");

To retrieve:
localstore.getItem("name");

use the above in your script section of the html page.